# Load function is not working after satisfying if condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, the if condition is working as I have checked with an alert but load function is not working.

My code:

```
$("a").click(function() {                            
    hreff = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hreff == "something" )
    {
        $("#dump").load("someurl");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent page reload
    var hreff = $(this).attr('href');
    if (hreff == "something") {
        $("#dump").load("someurl");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx...but i have to reload the page also...it's going inside if statement but not executing that load function

Comment: @SandeepKumar do you check that `hreff` is exactly `something`? can you post HTML?

Comment: it's a url and yes it's matching i have checked it putting alert box inside if statement ....

Comment: actually i have to set a session through this ..not exactly i m loading anything there...is there any other way to just execute a link like i m trying with load function ...

Comment: i don't it's funny or what but now when i am puuting an alert box just below that statement it's working...what u say??

Comment: @SandeepKumar you should debug with firebug or such like tools that load request is performing or not

Answer (score 0):

the function load will load the response from an defined url, but you hasn't defined an url.
if  $(this).attr('href') has an real url than you will never get them, becaus you check in your if for "something"

```
$("a").click(function() {
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href.length >0) {
        $("#dump").load(href, function() {
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
    }
});
```

This will work.

Comment: i thought for a minute it will work it's still not loading that url,though it's showing ur  alert('Load was performed.')